# Group presentations where discarding generators always yields a subgroup

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, universal-algebra

Consider a group presentation $ \left< G= \left\lbrace \text{generators}\right\rbrace \, \middle|\, R = \left\lbrace \text{relators}\right\rbrace \right>$ (no finiteness assumptions). Given $S\subset G$ let $R_S\subset R$ denote the subset made of all relators where only elements from $S$ are involved.
The property that I consider is that for any $S\subset G$, the group with presentation $ \left< S \, \middle|\, R_S \right>$ is "naturally" a subgroup of the original group—that is, via the map that sends any generator to "itself".

Does this property have a name or has it already been studied in a particular context?

Comment: For one-relator groups this is Magnus's freiheitssatz.  This property also holds for right angled artin groups.

Comment: Of course it is false in general because of silly things like $\langle x,y,z\mid xy^{-1}, yz^{-1},x\rangle$.

Comment: Note that this is a property of presentations and not of groups. This is true, as far as I know, for Coxeter and Artin presentations (as Benjamin Steinberg mentioned, of course with the given presentations). Note that some cases are trivial (e.g. **even** Artin/Coxeter presentations, i.e., where there are no finite odd labels — this encompasses right-angled Artin/Coxeter groups), since then killing a generator yields a retract. Also note that this is a property that is meaningful in universal algebra in general.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Indeed the context in which I'm looking at this is related to Artin groups (in particular braid group presentations have this property, but the usual virtual braid group presentations don't).

Comment: I think *Freheitssatz* (named after the famous theorem of Magnus mentioned by @BenjaminSteinberg) is the closest to a name that you will find for this. There have been many attempts to generalise the *Freheitssatz* in various ways, usually to various kinds of one-relator quotients -- see the *oeuvre* of Jim Howie and his collaborators... (tbc)

Comment: ... Perhaps the most interesting example of such a theorem is Howie's "locally indicable Freiheitssatz". (Recall that a group $G$ is *locally indicable* if every non-trivial subgroup surjects $\mathbb{Z}$.)  Howie proved that if $Y$ is a subcomplex of a 2-complex $X$, if $\pi_1Y$ is locally indicable, and if the relative second homology with rational coefficients $H_2(X,Y;\mathbb{Q})=0$ then the inclusion map $Y\to X$ is injective on $\pi_1$.

Comment: I think this is related to Abels-Holz higher generation, as in (https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0021869383711907?token=55FF69824A9A2B7D77F1CB0625B0397046CD4B94DA1FD055F8EFE273B7597AA66351573713BC2BE8A273FDC18154C1ED&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220326101649). More precisely this feels related to saying the group is "2-generated" by its subgroups generated by subsets of $S$. But off the top of my head I can't tell if this is equivalent.